# How do I build a recent modernizr?

Tags: modernizr

I used to add feature to my `modernirz` custom install using `https://modernizr.com/download/`, e.g:

```
https://modernizr.com/download?-flexbox-flexboxlegacy-flexboxtweener-flexwrap-fullscreen-geolocation-video-webp-setclasses-dontmin
```

or

```
https://new.modernizr.com/download?-flexbox-flexboxlegacy-flexboxtweener-flexwrap-fullscreen-geolocation-video-webp-setclasses-dontmin
```

but both seem old, and I need new features. Concretely, I need to detect h265 video playing, which seems to be in 3.11.0 of `new.modernizr.com`, but I cannot see it in `https://new.modernizr.com/download`.

Actually, `https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr` says:

> Our Website is outdated and broken, please DO NOT use it
> (https://modernizr.com) but rather build your modernizr version from
> npm.

Could anyone explain me in a detailed way how do I get the same result as when I could use the `https://modernizr.com/download/` page?

Comment: As they say, build from NPM. Instructions are on https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernizr.

Comment: ok, but what is the equivalent of `https://modernizr.com/download?-flexbox-flexboxlegacy-flexboxtweener-flexwrap-fullscreen-geolocation-video-webp-setclasses-dontmin`? `./bin/modernizr -o "flexbox,flexboxlegacy,flexboxtweener,flexwrap,fullscreen,geolocation,video,webp,setclasses,dontmin"` throws an error "throw new Error('invalid key value name - ' + prop);" in git/Modernizr/bin/modernizr:137. Same error if using `-f` instead o `-o`

Comment: Per the docs on that page, you need to do `modernizr.build` and consult https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/HEAD/lib/config-all.json for the available configuration parameters. Flexbox, for example, is `css/flexbox`, `css/flexboxlegacy`, etc. in the `feature-detects` configuration.

Comment: `./bin/modernizr -f "css/flexbox"` doesn't work!

Comment: "To see all available options run: `./bin/modernizr`"; "Or to generate everything in 'config-all.json' run this with npm: `npm start`". Have you done either of these?

Comment: `./bin/modernizr` is equivalent to `./bin/modernizr -h`: it explains how I can run the command, but it doesn't give my any info about the available features or options. I don't need the complete build, like the one got with `npm start`, I need to select my features

Comment: Per those documents, `npm start` generates a configuration file. Use that as a starting point.

Comment: documentation says that `npm start` generates "everything in 'config-all.json'": I tried it, and it build a complete modernizr.